# Formula for returning duplicated value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find duplicated data regardless of its order. I am dealing with 
17,000 dynamic data and I don’t want to use remove duplicate, use filter feature in excel or conditional formatting. I just want the formula for this. It would truly be more than appreciated if someone could give me a formula.

Example as follows where order of duplicates does not matter:
[image]

Comment: So, duplicate data, you mean: 1) the value should not repeat in that row. 2) If yes, is it applicable only for String values, because in row 4, i see the value 7 repeated but not flagged as duplicate.

Comment: @identifymecnu it looks like a duplicate is values in A:F exist in more than one row. Which, OP, is going to be crazy difficult with a formula.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @JNevill. Now I seem to understand what a duplicate is in here.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. An example is even given. Rows 2 and 5 both contain 2 apples, an 8, a 3, a 5 and a 7. Now... to turn this logic into a formula. That's not so clear. If these were just numeric values, then it might be reasonable, but "apple"... this is going to be one hell of a mess of formulas. I, personally, would go with VBA here because it would be 1000x easier, clearer, scalable, and maintainable.

Comment: @JNevill yeah but i dont want it to be a vba. any answer will do just pretend apple is a numeric value like 17 or something. i might just have to ditch accepting string this this way...

Comment: Why avoid VBA? That is like trying to build a house while avoiding hammers.

Comment: @John Coleman hammers hey? ahahah.. dude i wish i could agree with you but the person im about to hand this data has serious VBA trust issues he might blame me if something goes wrong with his PC. His like scared of VBA hacking and i mean i dont even know if a code such exist.

Comment: @NiñoTeves  This is easy with lots of *"helper"* cells........are you **OK** with this approach ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent huhuhuhu man i dont want helper cells ive tried that this would confuse the person im handing the data to. but if it looks good you are free to add answer bellow and i might check it as an answer.

Comment: I agree with @Gary'sStudent -- a non-VBA approach would almost require a lot of helper columns (unless you want an inscrutable mess). The resulting helper columns can be hidden or kept far off-screen.

Comment: can you create a formula for this if we say apple is 17? @JohnColeman?

Comment: That would be easier since then you could use `SMALL` and string concatenation to create unique identifiers, e.g. : `SMALL(A1:F1,1) & "#" & SMALL(A1:F1,2) & "#"&...` (etc.)

Comment: @JohnColeman You read my mind. Chip Pearson has a nice ready to use Array formula that does just what your thinking. I shared it in my almost-answer.

Comment: @JNevill Chip's approach is more robust. I was thinking of hard-wiring in the number of columns. Kudos to you for getting something to work out. I seldom have either the patience or the interest in making complicated array formulas when I know of a quick VBA solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm with you on that one. If this wasn't ready made, I wouldn't bother. I'll choose VBA over a complicated Array formula any day of the week. Or bring in ADO and attack it with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **G1** enter:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:F1, A1:F1))=COUNTA(A1:F1),"unique combination","duplicates")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This approach, based on JNevill's comment, does involve a little VBA.  If you cannot tolerate any VBA, ignore this Edit.

In a standard module, install the following code:

```
Public Sub aSort(ByRef InOut)

    Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
    Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function SortRow(rng As Range) As String
    ReDim ary(1 To rng.Count) As Variant
    Dim CH As String, i As Long
    CH = Chr(2)
    For i = 1 To 6
        ary(i) = rng(i)
    Next i
    Call aSort(ary)
    SortRow = Join(ary, CH)
End Function
```

`SortRow()` is a UDF that sorts the contents of the input range and displays the results in a single cell.

In **G1** enter:

```
=SortRow(A1:F1)
```

and copy down.  In **H1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$1:$G$7,G1)=1,"unique combination","duplicates")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: This works for one natural interpretation of the question -- the one I started with but which fails for row 4. I @JNevill is correct in the interpretation, then this unfortunately doesn't come close to answering the question. Still - it is a good answer for the natural reading of the question.

Comment: @JohnColeman  I do not understand........the picture in the question is in error since the value **7** appears more than once in row #4

Comment: @Gary'sStudent sorry dude the entire column is a combination. you need to find duplicated in the entire row. duplicated combination regardless the order.

Comment: @NiñoTeves   **Why is row #4 'unique' .....the value 7 appears more than once ??**

Comment: Think of each row as a *set* of values -- the set in row 2 is the same set as row 6. You can't determine if a row is a duplicate without looking at the overall data.

Comment: @JohnColeman  So one row cannot be a **combination** of the elements of another row ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Think of it as taking each row, sorting it ASC, concatenating the values together, and looking for duplicates amongst those concat'd values. :/

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this using Worksheet Formulas if all the values are numeric. Theoretically this should work with non-numeric as well, but it doesn't. It's very close, but the Array formula that sorts, duplicates positions when non-numerics enter the data.

As @Gary'sStudent mentioned, you are going to have to have a lot of helper columns. Your request is very very complex. I still think VBA is the best bet here. I guess it's your choice if you want to scare your end user with spooky VBA or scare them with lots of formulas. There's no way around it though. They are going to be terrified of whatever you hand them.

At any rate, I figured I'd share it since it may help:

Results:
[image]

Columns `H:M` contain a nasty array formula. [I stole it from Chip Pearson who has a nice explaination of it here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx). The formula sorts the values in each row. To enter the array formula you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter after putting the formula in. It will then get those curly braces to let you know that excel is treating it as an Array Formula.

[image]

Which we then Concatenate together in Column `N`:

[image]

And finally test to see if there are other concatenated sorted results that match:

[image]

Again, if you stick `Apple` into the mix, you will get incorrect sorts, but I think tweaking that Array formula will do the trick.